# Applying names and formats to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I'm trying to combine two arrays `(5000,2)` containing integers and `(5000,7)` containing float. I need to assign names to act as column headers when written to h5, however when I try to assign names and data types every column in the array gets repeated `9 times.`

My code is as follows:

```py
namesList = ['EID', 'Domain', 'LAM ID1', 'LAM ID2','LAM ID3', 'LAM ID4', 'LAM ID5', 'LAM ID6', 'LAM ID7']
formatsList = ['int', 'int', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float']

ds_dt = np.dtype({'names':namesList, 'formats':formatsList})

Final_Lam_Strength = np.concatenate((LAM_Strength_RFs_Data, LAM_Strength_RFs), axis=1).astype(ds_dt)
```

Thanks

Comment: don't use `astype` to create a structured array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Load data directly to HDF5**
If your goal is to load the data to HDF5 with h5py, there's no need to duplicate the data in another array. You can do it directly by creating the dataset then adding the data. The procedure is shown below with some simple data I created:

```
namesList = ['EID', 'Domain', 'LAM ID1', 'LAM ID2','LAM ID3', 'LAM ID4', 'LAM ID5', 'LAM ID6', 'LAM ID7']
formatsList = ['int', 'int', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float']

ds_dt = np.dtype({'names':namesList, 'formats':formatsList})

# the simple data
nrows, nints, nfloats = 5,2,7
LAM_Strength_RFs_Data = np.arange(nrows*nints).reshape(nrows,nints)
LAM_Strength_RFs = np.arange(nrows*nfloats).reshape(nrows,nfloats)

with h5py.File('SO_77346149.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    ds = h5f.create_dataset('Final_Lam_Strength',shape=(nrows,),dtype=ds_dt)   
    for i in range(nints):
        ds[namesList[i]] = LAM_Strength_RFs_Data[:,i]  
    for i in range(nfloats):   
        ds[namesList[i+2]] = LAM_Strength_RFs[:,i]
```

**Create NumPy structured array**
Now, if you really need a NumPy array, create it with with `np.empty()` and define the shape with the number of rows and the `dtype` with `ds_dt`. Then load the data using the named fields and column references.

This continues with data from example above:

```
Final_Lam_Strength = np.empty(shape=(nrows,),dtype=ds_dt)
print(Final_Lam_Strength.dtype, Final_Lam_Strength.shape)

for i in range(nints):
    Final_Lam_Strength[namesList[i]] = LAM_Strength_RFs_Data[:,i]

for i in range(nfloats):   
    Final_Lam_Strength[namesList[i+2]] = LAM_Strength_RFs[:,i]

print(Final_Lam_Strength[0]) # first row
print(Final_Lam_Strength[-1]) # last row
print(Final_Lam_Strength['Domain']) # 'Domain' column
```

**Create NumPy record array**
Function `np.core.records.fromarrays` is mentioned in the comments above. For completeness, here is an alternate method using that method. You do NOT need to create the empty array before calling this function.

```
arrayList = [LAM_Strength_RFs_Data[:,0], LAM_Strength_RFs_Data[:,1]] + \
            [LAM_Strength_RFs[:,i] for i in range(nfloats)]
             
Final_Lam_Strength = np.core.records.fromarrays(arrayList, dtype=ds_dt)
print(Final_Lam_Strength.dtype, Final_Lam_Strength.shape)
print(Final_Lam_Strength[0]) # first row
print(Final_Lam_Strength[-1]) # last row
print(Final_Lam_Strength.Domain) # access 'Domain' column by attribute name
```

**Notes on structured vs record arrays**
The 1st NumPy method creates a structured array, and the 2nd method method creates a record array. They are similar, but slightly different. Record arrays provide access to the field (column) using dot notation. Example print statements provided to show the difference. Also, the `np.core.records.fromarrays` method requires an intermediate data structure (the list of arrays). This won't be a problem with your data, but could be an issue if you have a lot of data (say 10E6 rows and 200 columns).

Comment: When I re-read your question, it occurred to me that you don't have to create a NumPy array if your goal is creating HDF5 dataset. Just load the data directly to the dataset. The procedure is almost identical. I modified my answer to show how to do that. I also added an example using `np.core.records.fromarrays`.

Answer (score 0):

The `empty` and copy by field approach in the other answer is good.  But `np.lib.recfunctions` has a utility function that may make this easier.

```
In [54]: namesList = ['EID', 'Domain', 'LAM ID1', 'LAM ID2','LAM ID3', 'LAM ID4', 'LAM ID5', 'LAM ID6', 'LAM ID7']
    ...: formatsList = ['int', 'int', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float', 'float']
    ...: 
    ...: ds_dt = np.dtype({'names':namesList, 'formats':formatsList})

In [55]: ds_dt
Out[55]: dtype([('EID', '<i4'), ('Domain', '<i4'), ('LAM ID1', '<f8'), ('LAM ID2', '<f8'), ('LAM ID3', '<f8'), ('LAM ID4', '<f8'), ('LAM ID5', '<f8'), ('LAM ID6', '<f8'), ('LAM ID7', '<f8')])

In [56]: ds_dt.fields
Out[56]: 
mappingproxy({'EID': (dtype('int32'), 0),
              'Domain': (dtype('int32'), 4),
              'LAM ID1': (dtype('float64'), 8),
              'LAM ID2': (dtype('float64'), 16),
              'LAM ID3': (dtype('float64'), 24),
              'LAM ID4': (dtype('float64'), 32),
              'LAM ID5': (dtype('float64'), 40),
              'LAM ID6': (dtype('float64'), 48),
              'LAM ID7': (dtype('float64'), 56)})
```

So you have a dtype with 9 fields, 2 of `int`, and 7 of `float`.

`concatenate` makes a (n,9) of floats:

```
In [57]: arr = np.concatenate((np.ones((3,2),int), np.ones((3,7),float)*2), axis=1)

In [58]: arr
Out[58]: 
array([[1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])

In [59]: arr.shape
Out[59]: (3, 9)

In [60]: rf
Out[60]: <module 'numpy.lib.recfunctions' from 'C:\\Users\\14256\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\lib\\recfunctions.py'>

In [61]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(arr, ds_dt)
Out[61]: 
array([(1, 1, 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.),
       (1, 1, 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.),
       (1, 1, 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.)],
      dtype=[('EID', '<i4'), ('Domain', '<i4'), ('LAM ID1', '<f8'), ('LAM ID2', '<f8'), ('LAM ID3', '<f8'), ('LAM ID4', '<f8'), ('LAM ID5', '<f8'), ('LAM ID6', '<f8'), ('LAM ID7', '<f8')])
```

I'm almost surprised that `unstructured_to_stuctured` works so well.

Here's an alternative dtype that keeps the 7 floats together:

```
In [62]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(arr, [('EID',int),('Domain',int),('LAM', float, 7)])
Out[62]: 
array([(1, 1, [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]),
       (1, 1, [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]),
       (1, 1, [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])],
      dtype=[('EID', '<i4'), ('Domain', '<i4'), ('LAM', '<f8', (7,))])
```

Assigning names to 'columns' can be handy for some purposes, but it makes working across the fields more awkward.  There are trade offs.